# Google Cloud Datastore access from Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to use Google Cloud datastore as remote data collector of a bunch of sensors, connected via an android Smartphone.

Firstly I'm trying to make it working in standard java.

The question is if it is possible to access Datastore directly from an android App of I need to build a GAE app that interact with the datastore.

I read for a while the documentation about the google api, but it is not really clear, how to use the Oauth 2.0 protocol.

Thank You all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the oath2 support built into android as long as every user of the app is an admin of your google cloud project/app engine app. If you want to allow untrusted users to upload data, you would have to use your own endpoint and authentication strategy.